# Вытащить из ответа JSON либо XML данные и в виде текста подставить в переменную PHP

Tags: php, json, парсер

Есть JSON ответ такого типа:

```
   {
  "suggestions": [
    {
      "value": "ИП Полухин Владислав Владимирович",
      "unrestricted_value": "ИП Полухин Владислав Владимирович",
      "data": {
        "citizenship": null,
        "fio": {
          "surname": "Полухин",
          "name": "Владислав",
          "patronymic": "Владимирович",
          "gender": null,
          "source": null,
          "qc": null
        },
        "source": null,
        "qc": null,
        "hid": "a018ad1acb35584283306d0b0620e712015fe7e2a6ace704461973bbf2ad55b3",
        "type": "INDIVIDUAL",
        "state": {
          "status": "ACTIVE",
          "code": null,
          "actuality_date": 1622073600000,
          "registration_date": 1621900800000,
          "liquidation_date": null
        },
        "opf": {
          "type": "2014",
          "code": "50102",
          "full": "Индивидуальный предприниматель",
          "short": "ИП"
        },
        "name": {
          "full_with_opf": "Индивидуальный предприниматель Полухин Владислав Владимирович",
          "short_with_opf": "ИП Полухин Владислав Владимирович",
          "latin": null,
          "full": "Полухин Владислав Владимирович",
          "short": null
        },
        "inn": "246505184496",
        "ogrn": "321246800066585",
        "okpo": "2008056724",
        "okato": "04401363000",
        "oktmo": "04701000001",
        "okogu": "4210015",
        "okfs": "16",
        "okved": "62.02",
        "okveds": null,
        "authorities": null,
        "documents": null,
        "licenses": null,
        "finance": null,
        "address": {
          "value": "г Красноярск",
          "unrestricted_value": "660000, Красноярский край, г Красноярск",
          "data": {
            "postal_code": "660000",
            "country": "Россия",
            "country_iso_code": "RU",
            "federal_district": "Сибирский",
            "region_fias_id": "db9c4f8b-b706-40e2-b2b4-d31b98dcd3d1",
            "region_kladr_id": "2400000000000",
            "region_iso_code": "RU-KYA",
            "region_with_type": "Красноярский край",
            "region_type": "край",
            "region_type_full": "край",
            "region": "Красноярский",
            "area_fias_id": null,
            "area_kladr_id": null,
            "area_with_type": null,
            "area_type": null,
            "area_type_full": null,
            "area": null,
            "city_fias_id": "9b968c73-f4d4-4012-8da8-3dacd4d4c1bd",
            "city_kladr_id": "2400000100000",
            "city_with_type": "г Красноярск",
            "city_type": "г",
            "city_type_full": "город",
            "city": "Красноярск",
            "city_area": null,
            "city_district_fias_id": null,
            "city_district_kladr_id": null,
            "city_district_with_type": null,
            "city_district_type": null,
            "city_district_type_full": null,
            "city_district": null,
            "settlement_fias_id": null,
            "settlement_kladr_id": null,
            "settlement_with_type": null,
            "settlement_type": null,
            "settlement_type_full": null,
            "settlement": null,
            "street_fias_id": null,
            "street_kladr_id": null,
            "street_with_type": null,
            "street_type": null,
            "street_type_full": null,
            "street": null,
            "stead_fias_id": null,
            "stead_cadnum": null,
            "stead_type": null,
            "stead_type_full": null,
            "stead": null,
            "house_fias_id": null,
            "house_kladr_id": null,
            "house_cadnum": null,
            "house_type": null,
            "house_type_full": null,
            "house": null,
            "block_type": null,
            "block_type_full": null,
            "block": null,
            "entrance": null,
            "floor": null,
            "flat_fias_id": null,
            "flat_cadnum": null,
            "flat_type": null,
            "flat_type_full": null,
            "flat": null,
            "flat_area": null,
            "square_meter_price": null,
            "flat_price": null,
            "postal_box": null,
            "fias_id": "9b968c73-f4d4-4012-8da8-3dacd4d4c1bd",
            "fias_code": "24000001000000000000000",
            "fias_level": "4",
            "fias_actuality_state": "0",
            "kladr_id": "2400000100000",
            "geoname_id": "1502026",
            "capital_marker": "2",
            "okato": "04401000000",
            "oktmo": "04701000001",
            "tax_office": "2400",
            "tax_office_legal": "2400",
            "timezone": "UTC+7",
            "geo_lat": "56.0093879",
            "geo_lon": "92.8524806",
            "beltway_hit": null,
            "beltway_distance": null,
            "metro": null,
            "divisions": {
              "administrative": {
                "area": null,
                "city": {
                  "fias_id": "9b968c73-f4d4-4012-8da8-3dacd4d4c1bd",
                  "kladr_id": "2400000100000",
                  "type": "г",
                  "type_full": "город",
                  "name": "Красноярск",
                  "name_with_type": "г Красноярск"
                },
                "settlement": null,
                "city_district": null
              },
              "municipal": null
            },
            "qc_geo": "4",
            "qc_complete": null,
            "qc_house": null,
            "history_values": null,
            "unparsed_parts": null,
            "source": "КРАЙ КРАСНОЯРСКИЙ, Г. КРАСНОЯРСК",
            "qc": "0"
          }
        },
        "phones": null,
        "emails": null,
        "ogrn_date": 1621900800000,
        "okved_type": "2014",
        "employee_count": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Необходим **PHP-код**, который вытащит из этого ответа JSON переменные **full_with_opf** , **status** и **value** в виде **простого текста**, которые потом можно использовать в переменных и оперировать с ними посредством PHP.

Ниже привожу код, как оно будет использоваться:

```
<?php
// STATUS полученный с JSON ответа    
$status = "ACTIVE";
//Текст переменной также полученный из JSON ответа    
$full_with_opf = "Индивидуальный предприниматель Полухин Владислав Владимирович";
// Текст переменной полученный из JSON ответа    
$value = "ИП Полухин Владислав Владимирович";
//Говорит на странице, что по данному ИНН организации найден предприниматель и сообщает его данные    
print_r($value);
// проверяет не закрыто ли ИП и позволяет продолжить заполнение регистрационной формы,
// либо делает что-то чтобы нельзя было продолжать регистрацию, поскольку запись о компании погашена в ФНС
if ($status != "ACTIVE"){
$start = "0"; }
// .... продолжение кода
?>
```

Заранее буду благодарен, особенно, если закомментируете код, чтобы можно было научиться, т.к. новичок. Прошу не судить строго за реализацию PHP.
Решение нужно, как можно скорее.

Comment: Это не JSON, это XML

Comment: Есть и JSON аналогичный ответ. Поправил, спасибо)

Comment: Вот теперь мы знаем все данные частного предпринимателя, лол.

Answer (score 1):

**XML**

```
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($res);
$status = $data->suggestions[0]->data->state->status;
$full_with_opf = $data->suggestions[0]->data->name->full_with_opf;
$value = $data->suggestions[0]->value;

print $status. ' ' .$full_with_opf. '' .$value;
```

**JSON**

```
$json = json_decode($res, true);
$status = $json[0]['suggestions'][0]['data']['state']['status'];
$full_with_opf = $json[0]['suggestions'][0]['data']['name']['full_with_opf'];
$value = $json[0]['suggestions'][0]['value'];
```

Где 'res' результат запроса. Думаю комментарии излишлни